# Vista no recibe datos de método para llenado de grafico

Tags: ajax, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, spring-mvc

Solicito de su apoyo, estoy intentando incrustar un grafico en una vista, trabajo con MVC / C# / SQL Server a traves de SP / VS2019.

Realice el proyecto por individual basado en tutoriales que encontre; ya que no he trabajado con gráficos antes, y logre el objetivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien intento meterlo dentro del proyecto final, y no logro generar el resultado previo, les comento llamo a un SP que filtra la información y lo deposita en un objeto de list, posteriormente en la vista con ajax, se llenan 2 arreglos con datos provenientes de un método del controlador el cual es este y depurando, se envía la información a través del método sin problema:

```
        public List<SICAL_Grafica_Facultad_ViewModel> GeneraDatosIndicadorFacultad()
    {
        List<SICAL_Grafica_Facultad_ViewModel> objLista = new List<SICAL_Grafica_Facultad_ViewModel>();
        string lcveent = Session["s_cve_ent"].ToString();
        string lcicesc = Session["s_cicloHorario"].ToString();
        string lperimp = Session["s_perHorario"].ToString();
        if ((lcicesc == null) || (lperimp == null))
        {
            lcveent = Session["s_cve_ent"].ToString();
            lcicesc = Session["s_ciclo"].ToString();
            lperimp = Session["s_periodo"].ToString();
        }
        using (CalificacionesEntities bdE = new CalificacionesEntities())
        {
            SqlParameter[] param_Calificaciones_sp_GeneraDatosFacultad = new SqlParameter[] {
                    //new SqlParameter ("@cic_esc", lcicesc),
                    //new SqlParameter ("@per_imp", lperimp),
                    //new SqlParameter ("@cve_ent", lcveent)
                };
            //Se ejecuta el spListaGrupos 
            var Lista_MuestraIndicadores = bdE.Database.SqlQuery<SICAL_Indicadores_Facultad_ViewModel>("CAL_sp_GeneraIndicadores", param_Calificaciones_sp_GeneraDatosFacultad).ToList();

            Lista_MuestraIndicadores.ForEach(dto => {
                var r = new SICAL_Grafica_Facultad_ViewModel();
                r.cve_car = dto.cve_car.ToString();
                r.decLogrado = decimal.Parse(dto.cLogrado.ToString().Substring(0, 5));
                // Esta línea es por que solo buscamos 2 caracteres que es del 90%
                r.iDeseado = int.Parse(dto.cDeseado.ToString().Substring(0, 2));
                // Esta línea aplica cuando se buscan 3 caracteres que es del 100%
                //r.iDeseado = int.Parse(dto.cDeseado.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
                objLista.Add(r);
            });
        }
        return objLista;
    }
```

El método retorna la lista con la información, tal cual lo hice en el proyecto individual. Pero en la vista del proyecto depurando con F12 en el mozilla observo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se llenan los arreglos al consultar el método del controlador previamente establecido, en la vista tengo el siguiente script:

```
section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
    //"~/scripts/chart.min.js";
    "~/Content/css/chart.min.css";
    var dtIndicadoresVar;
    var controlBar = document.getElementById("myBarChart");

    //Controles auxiliares para ejucutar la función cargadtProyeccion
    var ciclo = $("#_cic_esc").val()
    var iper = $("#_per_imp").val();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Función para llenado del dtIndicadores
        $('#btnConsulta').on('click', function () {
            //variables de controles seleccionados (filtro de búsqueda)
            var ciclo = $("#cic_esc").val();
            var iper = $("#per_imp").val();

            dtIndicadoresVar = $("#dtIndicadores").DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "url": "../Content/dt/datatableLanguage-es-mx.json",
                },
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "_all",
                    sortable: false
                }],
                //"responsive": "true",
                "dom": 'Bfrtilp',
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "extend": 'excelHtml5',
                        "text": '<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>',
                        "titleAttr": 'Exportar a Excel',
                        "className": 'btn btn-outline-success',
                        "exportOptions": { "columns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
                    }
                ],
                destroy: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Sical/LlenarGrillaIndicadorGeneral/",
                    //"url": "/g/Sical/LlenarGrillaIndicadorGeneral/",
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "data": { cic_esc: ciclo, per_imp: iper },
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",

                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "cve_car", className: "text-center" },
                    { "data": "cdescripcion_carrera" },
                    { "data": "TotalGruposPlantaDocente", className: "text-center" },
                    { "data": "EBienOrd", className: "text-center" },
                    { "data": "Destiempo", className: "text-center" },
                    { "data": "cLogrado", className: "text-center" },
                    { "data": "cDeseado", className: "text-center" }
                ],
            });



        });
    });

            //Grafico Indicadores
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GeneraDatosIndicadorFacultad", "Sical")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                /*console.log(data);*/

                var arrayCarreras = [];
                var arrayLogrado = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    /*console.log(data[i].mes)*/
                    arrayCarreras.push(data[i].cve_car)
                    arrayLogrado.push(data[i].decLogrado)
                }

                console.log(arrayCarreras)
                console.log(arrayLogrado)

                var controlBar1 = document.getElementById("myBarChart");

                var graficoBar1 = new Chart(controlBar1, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: arrayCarreras,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: "Indicadores de Facultad",
                                /*backgroundColor: "#0800B1",*/
                                backgroundColor: ["#03B100", "#0083B1", "#0800B1", '#007bff', '#dc3545', '#ffc107', '#28a745', "#03B100"],
                                borderColor: "#000000",
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                data: arrayLogrado,
                            }],
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                                    gridLines: {
                                        display: true
                                    },
                                }],
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        min: 0,
                                    },
                                    gridLines: {
                                        display: true
                                    }
                                }],
                            },
                            legend: {
                                display: true
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            });
            //Grafico Indicadores

    $('#dtIndicadores').on('click', 'tbody  tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var data = dtIndicadoresVar.row(this).data();
                //? cic_esc = " + ciclo + '&per_imp=' + iper,

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "@Url.Action("DetalleCarrera", "Sical")",
            data: { cve_car: data['cve_car'] },
            success: function (data) {
                var url = "@Url.Action("VerDetalleGrupo", "Sical")";
                location.href = url // + "/?cve_car=" + data['cve_car'];
            }
        });
    });

    //Acción Submit al dar clic en el botón Consultar Indicadores (recarga el dt)
    function ExecFormIndicadoresGenerales(form) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        dtIndicadoresVar.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

}

En la sección de //Grafico Indicadores es donde marco el inicio de lo que me generara la información para el grafico, pero no me genera lo esperado, me pueden por favor indicar el error cometido en la vista, cabe resaltar que en esta vista hago uso de un datatable y ciertos datos al inicio de la vista cargo 2 listados:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SICAL - Indicadores";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

List<CicloEscolar_ViewModel> SelectCiclo = ViewBag.ListadoCiclo_Bag;
List<PeriodoEscolar_ViewModel> SelectPeriodo = ViewBag.ListadoPeriodoBag;
```

}

Muchas gracias por la orientación.

Comment: Revisando, logre ya ver la data en la vista, pero me doy cuenta que no entra a un ciclo para recorrer la data con data.length lo marca como no definido.

Comment: Como trae "data" cuando le haces un console.log(data)?

Comment: Amigo Juan Carlos gracias por tomarte la molestia, he resuelto de la siguiente manera apuntando en el ciclo a data.data.lenght y lo mismo en los campos a insertar a los arreglos como data.data[i].cve_car y así sucesivamente.... desconozco por que hizo tal comportamiento...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto de la siguiente manera apuntando en el ciclo for en lugar de usar dat.length use data.data.length y lo mismo en los campos a insertar a los arreglos como data.data[i].cve_car y así sucesivamente.... desconozco por que hizo tal comportamiento de no reconocer la propiedad length con el data como se menciona al inicio.